# How to launch an Application with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, applescript, automator

Using only built-in functionality, how can I launch an Application such as Terminal by key command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simple way to launch any Application from a Service hot key.

Launch Automator, make a new Quick Action [Service].
In the search bar, type Launch.
Drag Launch Application into your workflow.
Select the Application name.
[Terminal itself doesn't show in the Applications list, so you have to use 'Other' & find it manually, in Applications/Utilities.]
Save the Quick Action & give it a useful name.

Find that name in the Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services menu, & add a hotkey.

[image]

Comment: For me, this only works if my "System Settings" app is open. Is anyone else facing this issue and has a workaround?

Comment: You really ought to raise this as a new question, linking back to this one. No-one is going to see it right down here.