# Shortcuts keeps forgetting keyboard shortcuts to its shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, shortcuts-app

I've set up half a dozen simple script actions with keyboard shortcuts in the Shortcuts app. They worked well for a long time, but a week or so ago it started repeatedly forgetting the configured shortcut keys (though fortunately not the actions themselves). (These are definitely not in use by anything else, so it's not a simple case of being overridden by a conflict.) Of course, I can add them back in, but that takes a while and I'm sure not going to do that every day. I'm using Monterey, 12.6.6, on a 2019 MBP. How do I get Shortcuts to do its *one job*?

Previous attempts at troubleshooting included restarting Shortcuts and exporting shortcuts to try to restore from backup.

Alternatively, what's a straightforward alternative solution to reliably run one-line shell commands on global hotkeys?

Comment: 'straightforward alternative solution' would be an Automator quick action [service] with an Applescript containing the shellscript - which can then be hot-keyed. Vaguely similar example  - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460091/85275