# What is shortcut to open terminal on macos high Sierra in virtualbox?

Tags: macos, terminal

What is keyboard shortcut to open terminal on macos high Sierra using normal keyboard without using macos keyboard that contain cmd and macos key in keyboard? I am just using logistics mk275 keyboard that used in normal windows and Linux also but what shortcut to open multiple or single terminal?
Can anyone know that ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no key command to launch Terminal in OS X.

You can launch it using Spotlight -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>  then typing Terminal & double clicking.

On a Windows keyboard the Windows <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>  key is recognised as  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, so just win+space.

Comment: There is not any shortcut to open terminal like in Linux or windows ?

Comment: No. You can make your own, though - [How to launch an Application with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460089/85275)