# How to open new Terminal windows directly on active Desktop [not on Desktop with other terminal windows]

Tags: macos, terminal, desktop, sonoma

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Make sure Terminal is not running
- Open a first Terminal window on Desktop1
- Switch to Desktop 2
- Open a new Terminal window using your favorite way

**Observations:**

- The new terminal windows opens on Desktop1, ie where the previous windows were.

**Desired Behavior:**

- I would like the new terminal window to open directly in the active Desktop, in that case: Desktop 2.

**Question 1: is it possible?**

**Alternatives considered:**

- If only I could at least define a default behavior where each new Desktop would automatically start one terminal window, that might be a sufficient workaround.

**Question 2: is this alternative possible?**

Comment: A ctrl click (or right click, double tap, long click) on the Dock icon of Terminal brings up the contextual menu to choose a new window, which also will open in the active Desktop (if Terminal hasn't been assigned to a Desktop).  No matter the Mission Control setting.

Comment: That's too many clicks already, since you have to click on "New Window" after that Ctrl+Click 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on one Mission Control Setting…
"When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application"

When this is **on** every time you try to open a new window, it will **first** switch to the Space the existing window is open on.
When **off** it doesn't do this initial switch & your new window will open on your current Space.

[image]

You may find this is a bit of a 'swings & roundabouts' setting. You will lose some other functionality this way - such as clicking an app in the dock or Cmd/Tabbing - the app will switch but the Space will not.

Comment: Thanks. That's sad, I actually like the Cmd/Tabbing switching to the appropriate space, especially when apps are in full-screen mode.

Comment: I accept the answer because I asked the wrong question. In fact, it's already off in my settings. I need to find a shortcut to open new Terminal Window instead of just looking for opened one. I guess that's my real problem when using the LaunchPad of the Dock

Comment: Ah, I don't have much experience of Launchpad, sorry - I took one look at it when it came out, thought it was far too much like having 8 screens of iPhone apps, & never looked at it again ;))

Comment: well, the 8 screens become easy to manage once you type the first letter of the app, or any substring of the appname, actually. Very handy when your fingers are on the keyboard. Anyways, my problem is also present in docker. If Terminal is open, clicking on it will only focus on it, not open new windows.

Comment: Remove the aspects I can't check, Launchpad & Docker - move to a Space without a Terminal window. Click Terminal in the Dock. It should just come to the front [appear in the menu bar] then Cmd/N should open a new window in that Space. [btw, having to type the name in Launchpad doesn't seem any different than doing it in Spotlight… which I don't use a lot either ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant Dock, not Docker. I guess I could use Spotlight, I just don't know the shortcut for it. My goal when using Launchpad is to not use the "mouse". I just have to pinch to trigger it, the mouse keeps its location on the screen. Anyways, we all have our habits :D

Comment: Spotlight default is Cmd/Spacebar. Personally, I use a lot of Spaces with specific apps on each. I switch apps by switching Spaces, rather than switching Spaces by switching apps [ctrl/num is default command set, but not enabled by default] That means I have one key command set to go to every app. I just have to remember which is on which Space, which isn't hard. I do have a lot on Space 1 - that requires I use the mouse, but it doesn't bother me to have to do that [horses for courses, as you say;)

Comment: Thanks for the spotlight shortcut. It goes very well, combined with the new AppScript suggested by ChatGPT (see answer below) :D

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering my real problem, which was not completely explained it the original Question, but, imho, doesn't deserve a new one...

### Here is ChatGPT answer:

To create a shortcut on a Mac desktop that opens a new Terminal window with each click, even if the Terminal is already open, follow these steps:

1. Open Script Editor:

- Go to the "Applications" folder, then to "Utilities".
- Launch "Script Editor".

2. Write the AppleScript Script:

- In Script Editor, write the following script:
  applescript

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    activate
end tell
```

- This script instructs the Terminal application to execute a new script (which is empty, so it just opens a new window) and to activate (take focus).

3. Save the Script as an Application:

- Go to "File" > "Save", or use the shortcut Command + S.
- Name your file, for example, "New Terminal Window".
- Choose a location to save, such as the Desktop.
- Importantly: in the format, choose "Application".
- Click on "Save".

4. Use the Shortcut:

- You will now see a new application on your desktop with the name you chose.
- Each time you click on this application, a new Terminal window will open.

5. (Optional) Change the Application Icon:

- If you want to change the icon of this shortcut, you can find an icon you like, copy this icon (in .icns format if possible), right-click on the application you created, select "Get Info", and paste the icon in the upper-left corner of the info window.

With these steps, you should have a functional shortcut on your Mac desktop that opens a new Terminal window with each click.

Comment: You could do the same as a Service [Quick Action] which would then be key commandable [and also not have to go through launching & quitting an app each time.] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460091/85275 Replace the launch action with your script.